# Read HTML Table in c# without HTMLagility pack

Tags: c#, html

I am using Windows app to read a HTML table which in format

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
```

i am able to read values by tr or td,but i am not able to read second tr value as per corresponding first tr heading(eg first name/eve) here.how can i achieve this.any suggestions welcome please

Comment: please post the code you're useing

Comment: If the HTML you're reading is valid XHTML rather than [tag soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup), then you could use the builtin XML/XPath libraries to parse it.